# Populating two tables from another table using a trigger

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I am having the following issue:

I currently have 3 tables:

```
Person(personID, firstName, lastName, ...)
Household(householdID, personID, sons, daughters, ...)
Info(infoID, firstName, lastName, sons, daughters, ...)
```

The Info table is where all of the data is currently, while Person and Household are empty and I would like to distribute the data by putting the persons data into the Person table, and their household data into the Household table. Household.personID is a foreign key to Person.personID.

I am attempting to do this by inserting one row at a time into household, and after each row I will insert the persons data into the Person table (which will assign that person a unique personID) and then go back and insert that new personID into the household table.

After looking around I have found that I should either be using a transaction or a by creating a trigger (or both?). I do not know much about either but this is what I have created from what I have read:

```
CREATE TRIGGER PersonTrigger AFTER INSERT ON Person
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Household
    (personID, sons, daughters, ...")
    VALUES (LAST_UPDATE_ID(), (SELECT sons, daughters, ...
    FROM Info)
    END;

INSERT INTO Person (firstName, lastName, ...)"
    SELECT firstName, lastName, ... 
    FROM Info
```

But when attempting to run this I am getting the SQLException error

```
SQLException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO TestHousehold(personID, givenName, lastName' at line 1
```

Any insight as to why this may be happening would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you post entire trigger code?

Comment: `I am attempting to do this by inserting one row at a time into household` You are inserting data into houhold table...so, use before trigger and fire it no the household take the data insert it into the persons table get **maxid** and then insert it into the household table.

Comment: @MatteoRubini I have never used triggers before and after reading into it more I see that I need to set a `DELIMITER` and have an `END` after my trigger code. Is that what you meant by posting my entire trigger code, or is there more that I am missing?

Comment: Seems the problem is not in your trigger syntax (create ... Insert into .... Ecc..) , it's possibile you have a missing bracket, missing quotes, ecc... But i cant Check cause cant see entire code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER distributing_info_details AFTER INSERT ON Info FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO Household (personID, sons, daughters, ...)
    VALUES (new.PersonID, new.sons, new.daughters, ...)
    # use    ^ this key word to access the newly inserted ID.
  INSERT INTO Person (firstName, lastName, ...)
    VALUES (new.firstName, new.lastName,...)
END;
```

Please note that the **two insert statements must be both between** the `BEGIN` and `END` tags. And also note that I attached this trigger after `insert` on the `Info` table, not on `Person` because you said that all data are currently put on `Info` table.

You didn't tell us whether `sons` and `daughter` also refers to another `person` (which in that case, `sons` and `daughters` are `foreign keys`), and will yield to a different set of codes for this `trigger`.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The problem was that I was updating Household while creating a trigger for after insert into Household and thus creating an infinite loop.